# Collect consumers' information

Tags: c#

When you install an application in Windows, you often see a dialog that asks the user if they'd like to participate in a program and send system or application information to the software publisher.  If the software crashes, it might also send failure information. How can an application send information from the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is done by communicating with some kind of server application ( [webservice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) for example).

There is alot of frameworks to help you build this kind of application;
for example:

With Java you can use [Java Web Services Developer Pack](http://java.sun.com/webservices/downloads/previous/index.jsp)

PHP has SOAP Extension - you can read its manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php)

With .NET you can use [Windows Communications Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) framework. I think this [tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication) can be a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

Typically the client application collects system information and transmits that to a 'web service' interface on the server via HTTP POST.

Comment: Could you give more detail about it?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may be also interested in a open-source library for trapping bugs and transmitting them to the author of the program (file, email, script, etc). It is called BugTrap. See here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/BugTrap.aspx